# Is $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$  a field ?

We know that $\mathbb Q$ is a field. But, if we think of $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$, what would be the answer?

Comment: Hint: what's the inverse of $(0,a) \in \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $0 \neq a,b\in K$ for a field $K$ we have that $(a,0) \cdot (0,b)=(0,0)$ , so $K \times K$ is not an integral domain, hence not a field.

Comment: thank you... super...@mesih

Comment: You are welcome